# How to Parse date in Simple date format in arabic locale?

Tags: java, android, localization

i have date  coming from server & is in the format = "2013-01-20T16:48:43" my application support Both Arabic & English Locale. But when i change the locale to Arabic the date is not parsing its giving me parse exception. till now what i have written is

```
private static Date parseJsonDate(final String string) throws Exception
    {
    final String change_Locale = Locale.getDefault().getISO3Language();
            if (change_Locale.equalsIgnoreCase("ara"))
            {

                System.out.println(":: Date :::" + string);
                final SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", new Locale("ar"));

                System.out.println("new date " + format.parse(string));
                return format.parse(string);
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce. I get `Sun Jan 20 16:48:43 CET 2013`.

Comment: For new readers to the question I strongly recommend that you do not use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class was notoriously troublesome and is long outdated. Use `LocalDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html). It can parse your string without the need for specifying any formatter.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do not parse your date into the Arabic it will give you error alwayz besides try as below by setting the Locale ENGLISH only.

```
final SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: @ Grishu Locale.Arabic is not supported in java

Comment: `, Locale.ENGLISH` this on app language change not working

Answer (score 4):

Your error seems to be due to some bug in the older version of Java.

Note that in March 2014, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html) supplanted the legacy date-time API and since then it is strongly recommended to switch to `java.time`, the modern date-time API.

The `java.time` API has a specialised type, `LocalDateTime` to represent an object that has just date and time units, and no timezone information.

**Demo**:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", new Locale("ar"));
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("2013-01-20T16:48:43", parser);
        System.out.println(ldt);

        // Alternatively, as suggested by Basil Bourque
        parser = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME.withLocale(new Locale("ar"));
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse("2013-01-20T16:48:43", parser));

        // Your parser
        final SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", new Locale("ar"));
        System.out.println(format.parse("2013-01-20T16:48:43"));
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2013-01-20T16:48:43
2013-01-20T16:48:43
Sun Jan 20 16:48:43 GMT 2013
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/DjBeEa)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: Thanks, @BasilBourque. I have incorporated your suggestion in my answer.

Comment: @BasilBourque We don’t even need any explicit formatter. `LocalDateTime.parse("2013-01-20T16:48:43")` does it.

Comment: Thanks, @OleV.V. It was necessary for demonstrating the use of `Locale`.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Yes, I did not know if calling `withLocale` on the constant would work or not.

Comment: Do we really need a `Locale` at all here? If we have a `String` object such as `"2013-01-20T16:48:43"` in hand, then we are simply parsing Unicode text. There is nothing localized about it, nothing to do with Arabic specifically.