# Unable to parse date for arabic locale

Tags: java, datetime, locale, arabic, date-parsing

```
public class DateParser {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateString = "2015-07-20";
        try
        {   
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
            Date dt=dateFormat.parse(dateString);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Above is my code piece. I'm trying to parse a date string.  Its working fine if my locale is US. If i change it to Arabic (In calendar settings. I'm using windows machine), its not working. getting below error.

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-07-20"
        at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
        at DateParser.main(DateParser.java:34)
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your code works for me. Did you import the correct libraries? (`java.util.Date`, `java.text.SimpleDate.format`)

Comment: Ofcourse I did. Its actually working for me too if the locale is US. But fails in case of Arabic.

Comment: Did you try the "dd/mm/yyyy" format ? [Wikipedia > Saudi Arabia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Parse date in Simple date format in arabic locale?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439315/how-to-parse-date-in-simple-date-format-in-arabic-locale)

Comment: check is your locale supported by class which are you using, try `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(SimpleDateFormat.getAvailableLocales()));`

Comment: @superbob Yes I did with "2015/07/20". Its working. But why the same is not working with "2015-07-20"

Comment: It seems "yyyy/MM/dd" is not a valid string format for the Arabic locale. I think you should really consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439315/how-to-parse-date-in-simple-date-format-in-arabic-locale as proposed by @user902383

Comment: @superbob  You mean "yyyy/MM/dd" is not valid or "yyyy-MM-dd"  is not valid??

Comment: My bad, I meant "yyyy-MM-dd", not "yyyy/MM/dd"

Comment: Maybe you are sitting in a country which prefers indo-arabic digits not the standard arabic digits 0-9. What does `Locale.getDefault()` output?