# Converting arbaic string date to english date

Tags: java, string, date

Is there any way to convert this :

```
String arabicDate = "الأحد 11 يناير 2015 - 20:40";
```

To this :

```
String englishDate = "11/01/2015 20:40"
```

Edit:

I tried this:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final String dateStr = "الأحد 11 يناير 2015 - 20:40";
    try {
        final Date date = new SimpleDateFormat(("dd MMMM yyyy - hh:mm"), new Locale("ar", "Morocco"))
                .parse(dateStr);
        System.out.println(date);
    } catch (final ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The output:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "الأحد 11 يناير 2015 - 20:40"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
at com.marocalite.core.common.theme.service.ThemeReaderManagerImpl.main(ThemeReaderManagerImpl.java:97)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Parse date in Simple date format in arabic locale?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439315/how-to-parse-date-in-simple-date-format-in-arabic-locale)

Comment: hi I doubt there is no way but still try this
Date tradeDate = new SimpleDateFormat("FormatOfDate(e.g. yyyymmdd)", new Locale("ar")).parse(arabicDate);
But I see some English number too and it may be country specific..
Also you can refer to list of locales at http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/i18n/locales-list.shtml

Comment: @Prashant this is not the same question

Comment: @Anarki : i didn't downvote but i thought this might be same problem.

Comment: @viraj your solution is not working, i also thought that is linked to a specific country which is Morocco but the problem is still not solved

Comment: Obviously "dd MMMM yyyy - hh:mm" cannot be correct, maybe it's "hh:mm - yyyy MMMM dd EE" or something? I don't read arabic so I have no clue if/where there is a day/month name there.

Comment: @Bram thanks for your, but "hh:mm - yyyy MMMM dd EE" is not working !

Comment: @Bram it's Sunday January 11. Try using "EEEE, MMM dd, yyyy - HH:mm"

Comment: Using Joda-Time and Google Translate (I don't know Arabic), I did learn that the longer piece of Arabic text is the long form of "January", so you do indeed need to use four m's (`MMMM`) to avoid the Arabic equivalent of "Jan". That's one piece of the puzzle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following code:

```
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final String dateStr = "الأحد 11 يناير 2015 - 20:40";
        try {
            final Date date = new SimpleDateFormat(("EEEE dd MMM yyyy - HH:mm"), new Locale("ar", "MA"))
                    .parse(dateStr);
            System.out.println(date);
        } catch (final ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```