# simpleDateFormatter not working on websphere

Tags: java, parsing, date, simpledateformat

I am working on Java 1.7 on ubuntu. 
My code and functionality is working fine. But when I deployed it on Websphere then `java.text.SimpleDateFormatter` is not working... 
And its displaying parse error.My websphere enviornment has linux and Java 1.4.2. If anyone knows about this issue, please help me.

here is my code

```
public static String formatDate(String commingDate){

        String formatedDate = "00-00-00";
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            Date date = sdf.parse(commingDate);
            formatedDate =  sdf.format(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            log.error(e);
        }   
        return formatedDate;
    }
```

Comment: What parse error?  What format are you using and what is the `String` value you are trying to parse?

Comment: Are you speaking about `SimpleDateFormat`? Please show us how it's constructed and used in your code.

Comment: How are you getting the date that is passed to the formatter?

Comment: What values fail to work using the supplied code?

Comment: Please add the exact value of `commingDate` string which causes the error (if you have exception log, it should be displayed in the exception message).

Comment: What does this method even do? You are effectively returning the same String that was passed as argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SimpleDataFormat(String)` constructor uses default system locale. It's possible that your Websphere server has the different default locale which causes different behavior. Try to specify the locale explicitly:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439315/how-to-parse-date-in-simple-date-format-in-arabic-locale) answer for similar problem.

Comment: That would be an issue if the format included day or month names, but the supplied format doesn't.  Would it affect numbers?

Comment: Probably you're right. It works for every locale installed on my system, though for some obscure locales it returns different year. On the other hand we did not see yet what's actual input is used by OP.