# How do I convert an Arabic String date to a java 8 date object?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, arabic, arabic-support

I'm working on a web monitoring project in Arabic and I want to convert string date like this one:

```
الاثنين 24 أبريل 2017 - 15:00
```

to Java 8 date object. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried using the Locale for a country that uses Arabic? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29154887/setting-arabic-numbering-system-locale-doesnt-show-arabic-numbers/29155743#29155743

Comment: Is this not addressed already in the 34 hits found when [searching for “java arabic date”](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+arabic+date)?

Answer (score 9):

Edit: with thanks to slim and Meno Hochschild for inspiration:

```
String dateTimeString = "الاثنين 24 أبريل 2017 - 15:00";

DateTimeFormatter formatter
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE d MMMM uuuu - HH:mm", new Locale("ar"));
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeString, formatter);
System.out.println(dateTime);
```

This prints:

```
2017-04-24T15:00
```

Comment: Just construct the locale without nu-extension. It works without and should fail with your nu-extension (but does not), see my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, @MenoHochschild. On my computer even `new Locale("ar")` works, so I have put that in instead of the complicated language tag.

Answer (score 5):

The answers of @Ole and @slim are working, but not for the reason they think.

**First observation - the nu-extension is unnecessary for given example:**

Oles suggestion would also work for the locale `new Locale("ar", "SA")` instead of `Locale.forLanguageTag("ar-SA-u-nu-arab")`. So what does the unicode-nu-extension here? Nothing. Next question:

**What is the nu-extension supposed to do here?**

The nu-code-word "arab" is [specified by the unicode consortium](http://www.unicode.org/repos/cldr/tags/release-31-0-1/common/supplemental/numberingSystems.xml) to yield arabic-indic digits. But the **input to be parsed does only have western digits 0-9** (which are historically overtaken from Arab people and specified as code word "latn" - a misnomer by the way). So if the nu-extension had really done its job here then **parsing should have failed** because [arabic-indic digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals) are not 0-9 but:

> ٠     ١   ٢   ٣   ٤   ٥   ٦   ٧   ٨   ٩

Obviously, the nu-extension is not supported in general by new time-API in Java-8.

**Does `SimpleDateFormat` support the nu-extension?**

Using debugging of following code, I discovered that the nu-extension is only supported for Thai-numerals (see also official javadoc of class `java.util.Locale` but not for arabic-indic digits:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = 
    new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE d MMMM yyyy - HH:mm", Locale.forLanguageTag("ar-SA-nu-arab"));
Date d = sdf.parse(dateTimeString);
System.out.println(d);
String formatted = sdf.format(d);
System.out.println(formatted);
System.out.println(sdf.format(d).equals(dateTimeString));

sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE d MMMM uuuu - HH:mm", Locale.forLanguageTag("ar-SA-u-nu-thai"));
String thai = sdf.format(d);
System.out.println("u-nu-thai: " + thai);
```

I assume the class `DateTimeFormatter` of Java-8 also supports Thai numerals.

**Conclusion:**

Forget the nu-extension. Just construct the locale via the old-fashioned way without unicode extension and adapt Oles answer this way. It works because your input only has western digits 0-9.

For extensive i18n-support including the nu-extension for various numbering systems (if you have such input), you might consider external libraries (for example ICU4J or my lib Time4J).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know enough Arabic to understand an Arabic formatted date. However this code:

```
Locale arabicLocale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguageTag("ar-SA-u-nu-arab").build();

LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.FULL).withLocale(arabicLocale);

String formatted = date.format(formatter);
System.out.println(formatted);
System.out.println(formatter.parse(formatted));
```

Yields this output:

```
26 أبريل, 2017
{},ISO resolved to 2017-04-26
```

The code to create the `Locale` is from an answer to [Setting Arabic numbering system locale doesn't show Arabic numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29154887/setting-arabic-numbering-system-locale-doesnt-show-arabic-numbers/29155743#29155743)

You can fine-tune this format by defining your own `FormatStyle`.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to translate the date to English and parse it then:

```
private final static Map<String, Integer> monthMapping = new HashMap<>();
static {
    // list of all month.
    monthMapping.put("أبريل", "4");
}


public Date fromArabicToDate(String arabicInput) throws ParseException {
    String[] parts = arabicInput.split(" ");
    if (parts.length != 4) 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    String dateInput = parts[0] + "-" + monthMapping.get(parts[1]) + "-" + parts[2];
    SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD");
    return parser.parse(dateInput);
}
```

I tried to copy the month but I don't believe I have done it correctly. The arguments of `put` get switched when parsing.

Or you have a look at [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). Maybe they have a solution. It was [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21809720/2097191).

Comment: Oh... obsolete information. You never stop learning. Thanks @Hulk. This was somewhere in the back of my mind. I found this where it says the same but it is more than 4 years old: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14439397/2097191  (I changed my answer)

Comment: The answer you are referring to seems to be about a limitation of [one specific constructor of `SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat-java.lang.String-java.util.Locale-): "Constructs a SimpleDateFormat using the given pattern and the default date format symbols for the default FORMAT locale. Note: This constructor may not support all locales. For full coverage, use the factory methods in the DateFormat class."

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the charset when parsing the string, assuming that the date you want to parse will always be in the format you provided this would work :

```
public static Date getDate(String strDate) throws Exception{
    strDate=new String(strDate.getBytes(),"UTF-8");

    Map<String, Integer> months = new HashMap<>();

    String JAN =  new String("يناير".getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    String FEB =  new String("فبراير".getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    String MAR =  new String("مارس".getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    String APR =  new String("أبريل".getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    String APR_bis =  new String("ابريل".getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    String MAY =  new String("ماي".getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    String JUN =  new String("بونيو".getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    String JUN_bis =  new String("يونيه".getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    String JUL =  new String("يوليوز".getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    String AUG =  new String("غشت".getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    String SEP =  new String("شتنبر".getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    String SEP_bis =  new String("سبتمبر".getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    String OCT =  new String("أكتوبر".getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    String OCT_bis =  new String("اكتوبر".getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    String NOV =  new String("نونبر".getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    String NOV_bis =  new String("نوفمبر".getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    String DEC =  new String("دجنبر".getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    String DEC_bis =  new String("ديسمبر".getBytes(), "UTF-8");



    months.put(JAN, 0);
    months.put(FEB, 1);
    months.put(MAR, 2);
    months.put(APR, 3);
    months.put(APR_bis, 3);
    months.put(MAY, 4);
    months.put(JUN, 5);
    months.put(JUN_bis, 5);
    months.put(JUL, 6);
    months.put(AUG, 7);
    months.put(SEP, 8);
    months.put(SEP_bis, 8);
    months.put(OCT, 9);
    months.put(OCT_bis, 9);
    months.put(NOV, 10);
    months.put(NOV_bis, 10);
    months.put(DEC, 11);
    months.put(DEC_bis, 11);


    StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(strDate);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();


    while(stringTokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {

        stringTokenizer.nextElement();// to skip the first string which is the name of the day

        int day = Integer.parseInt(stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString().trim());

        String strMonth = stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString().trim();

        int month = months.get(strMonth);

        int year = Integer.parseInt(stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString().trim());

        calendar.set(year, month, day);


    }
    return calendar.getTime();

}
```

it gives this output :

```
  Fri Oct 20 15:26:47 WEST 2017
```

Comment: I am missing the point in your string conversions. On my computer `new String("يناير".getBytes(), "UTF-8")` yields the same string as just `"يناير"`. Same for all the other month names. The result may be different on a computer with a different default character set.

Comment: yeah @OleV.V. it was added to specify that the wanted charset is `UTF-8`